# Would it be bad to ask these questions?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, questions, specific-question

I wanted to ask if anyone knows how long before WTF changes its rules. Apparently, I heard that they are trying to make it more like MMA, by doing things like allowing punches to the face. If anyone has heard of this, maybe they can answer my question. But first, is that question inappropriate?

I also wanted to know if it would be stupid to ask if I should add in BJJ and another martial art after I get my black belt in TKD, or if that would be a waste of time and I should do it before. I just want to make sure because I'm thinking of starting something else in the short run that isn't a martial art and I don't know if I should do that or BJJ. I wanted to ask the same thing about the second question.

Answer (score 1):

> I wanted to ask if anyone knows how long before WTF changes its rules....But first, is that question inappropriate?

It can be, it depends on how you ask the question and how much information you include when you ask. Asking for confirmation of an unsubstantiated rumour is pretty pointless. If you can include links or references to events that have happened or online materials it will have a much better chance of being an answerable question.

> I also wanted to know if it would be stupid to ask if I should add in BJJ and another martial art after I get my black belt in TKD, or if that would be a waste of time and I should do it before.

To be honest, this sort of question is not encouraged - mainly because the answer depends on many things (it depends on you, it depends on the teachers you'll be learning from, etc etc.). This sort of question tends to attract opinion - some of it learned, some of it not so. Therefore we try to avoid it - we prefer things that can be answered definitively.